# How do I properly monitor a Per Session WCF client

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, .net-4.0, event-handling

So I'm consuming a Per Session WCF service with a Reliable WSHttpBinding. As it is Per Session I need to handle any problem I have with the channel but my knowledge of WCF isn't really good yet.

I decided to subscribe to the faulted event of ClientBase.InnerChannel thinking this would fire if something came up. This however seems to only fire in specific cases.

For example I connected in and then unplugged from the network the service is on and faulted wasn't thrown, even when I tried to do something I only got the EndPointNotFound exception.

Is there anyway I can monitor an event that fires anytime a channel becomes unusable for any reason? I would love in would do that at the instance I get disconnected or a timeout occurs but even if that is not possible (without busy waiting constantly checking) I would be happy with something that let's me know as soon as I try something.

Comment: if a transport session stop your proxy should throw an exception, it could be a communicationexception, a timeoutexception or others, i don't understand when you do not have this behavior

Comment: Yes a exception is thrown, problem is I wan't to handle it in one place instead of many. Well mainly, what I was shooting for was that I would know beforehand that the connection was dead, so as soon as I unplugged from the net I would get a event on the proxy that the channel had faulted. I wasn't sure that would work, hence the question (think the connection thing in the statusbar of outlook). If that won't work I have a ClientManager class wrapped around the proxy and I would love if I can handle everything there. But all proxy calls are made outside of this class.

Answer (score 0):

you can host WCF Service in windows server appfabric which allow you to use a lot of tools to monitor wcf :
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=771

Comment: I guess monitor wasn't the correct word for me to use because this is nothing close to what I'm talking about. I'm a consumer, not the host of the service.

Comment: to monitor properly you can use  ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout to a period that is short enough it will throw an exception when timeout

Comment: The strange thing is that I've tried to lower that to 10 seconds, as well as receiveTimeout but it doesn't seem to timeout at all. It's like there is a secret keep alive code built into PerSession service or it's overwritten by service code.